# How to output the name of the files through the waveform?

Tags: labview

Morning,

Here is my problem,

I am trying to save the data captured from the Condition Monitoring system,the code we are using now is only for getting the parameters. I'd like to save the files which has crossed the threshold.

Now I have the waveform from the data, how can I get the files through it?

The files should be TDMS, the data is acquired by FPGA.

Thank you very much!

Kind regards

Jialin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TDMS Write and set there your channels and groups. Also you can set properties to your data using TDMS properties.

Have a look on examples. For examples this one seems good for you: TDMS Write Triggered Data VI: labview\examples\File IO\TDMS\Standard Read and Write